# How to generate unique_id for send_mail in php

Tags: php, sendmail, unique-id

Currently we have send_mail and this fucntion called in different files.

We have auto_mailer that concatenate report subscription emails with the emails address which are generated programmatically.

My task is to generate uniqueId so that we don't have to change/manually add send_mail params/arguments on each files where send_mail function called.

The generated uniqueId must represent the send_mail function where it was called.

We already tried using debug_backtrace() and convert it via sha1() to generate uniqueId but the problem is the future changes in code.

We already tried to use send_mail params/arguments and convert it via sha1() to generate uniqueId but the problem is the params/arguments data is dynamic.

Here's the sample code:

```
$subject = 'Tickets 1st QTR 2020';

// 1st scenario
function send()
{
    send_mail('',$recipient.'', "Reports Guy", $sender, $subject);
}

function send2()
{
    send_mail('',$recipient.'', "Reports Guy", $sender, $subject);
}

// 2nd scenario: uniqueId shoud remain the same even there's a change/update in php code
function send()
{
    // must be same uniqueId
    send_mail('',$recipient.'', "Reports Guy", $sender, $subject);
}

function send3()
{
    // must be different uniqueId
    send_mail('',$recipient.'', "Reports Guy", $sender, $subject);
}

function send2()
{
    // must be same uniqueId
    send_mail('',$recipient.'', "Reports Guy", $sender, $subject);
}

function send_mail($module,$to_email,$from_name,$from_email,$subject,$contents,$cc='',$bcc='',$attachment='',$emailid='',$logo='',$set='',$filename='')
{    
    global $DEV_TEST_ENV;   
    global $DEV_TEST_EMAIL; 
    global $DEV_FROM_EMAIL; 
    
    // add code here that generate and check uniquedId in tbl_subscriptions
    // create new entry if not exist else continue to send.

    $mail_log = preg_replace("/\s{2}/", "", nl2br("'".$module."','".$to_email."','".str_replace(array("'", "\n"), "", $from_name)."','".$from_email."','".str_replace(array("'", "\n"), "", $subject)."','','".$cc."','".$bcc."','".$attachment."','".$emailid."','".$logo."'"));

        
    return $mail_error;
}
```

Example:

In scenario #1 in above, lets assume that send2() is in line 22 and generate uniquedId - 123asd.

In scenario #2 send2() is moved in line 32 or the params was changed, how can i generate the same uniqueId?

Comment: Where exactly is a problem with that uniqueIds? How does the implementation of `send_mail` look like?

Comment: maybe if you explain **why** you need this unique id we could be much more helpful and give you a clean solution to your problem.

Comment: You have to explain your problem  a bit more, now i see 4 functions with the same call.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your replies. I already updated my question.
i add 
"The generated uniqueId must represent the send_mail function where it was called.
"

and the sample send_mail function

Comment: So basically you want to log which other function called the send_mail function, is that right? You still haven't fully explained what the purpose of all this is. You seem to be trying to avoid making some changes in your code...but what those changes are, and why it's a problem to make them, is still a mystery.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question again sorry this is my first time. Here's my example:

Example:

In scenario #1 in above, lets assume that send2() is in line 22 and generate uniquedId - 123asd.

In scenario #2 send2() is move in line 32 or the params was change, how can i generate the same uniqueId?